# Apply hook_menu to all nodes except node593

Tags: nodes, routes

I have 2 separate hook_menu callbacks going on in my code.

I want to apply a function to all nodes and then for node593, I want to apply it's own function but I can't seem to do this.

The function for the % wildcard seems to work for all nodes, including 593.

Anyone know how I can get past this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably overthinking it; making that decision in the page callback seems like the easiest solution:

```
function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['node/%node']['page callback'] = 'MYMODULE_node_page';
}

function MYMODULE_node_page($node) {
  if ($node->nid == 593) {
    return node_page_view($node);
  }
  else {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that I create this new function and that the page_callback in hook_menu will call this new function ?

Comment: That's the idea, yes. If you're overriding an existing path (node/%node in this case) you should do it in `hook_menu_alter` rather than `hook_menu` - it's more reliable

Comment: Sorry just to be clear, The new page_callback is MYMODULE_menu_alter because it still is not working correctly

Comment: The page callback would be `MYMODULE_node_page` in the example above...the `hook_menu_alter` is what you'd ideally be using to override the callback function for the node page. If you can edit the code you're using into the question I can advise a bit better

Comment: `code` function antenna_menu() {
 $items['support/download/file/nojs/593'] = array(
     'page callback' => 'antenna_node_alter',
     'page arguments' => array(3, 4),
     'access callback' => true,
     'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,`code`

Comment: function antenna_node_page($node) {
  if ($node->nid == 593) {
    'antenna_check_antenna';
  }
  else {
    'antenna_check_download';
  }
}

Comment: antenna_check_antenna is the function I want to use for node593 and antenna_check_download is the function I want to use for all other nodes